# Trying to describe a field for a user guide

Tags: single-word-requests

The field is "Previous login". Which of the two options is more concise?

> 1. The duration since the last login
> 2. The length of time since the last login.

A colleague mentioned it should be (2) because "duration" needs to be applied to a subject, e.g. "duration of". Is this correct?

I'm leaning towards (1) because duration=length of time.

Comment: Your colleague is right in saying that duration = "length of time _of_". Another more concise alternative would simply be _Time since last login_.

Comment: Time since last login: That's it, short and sweet.

Comment: "Time since" was my initial thought, also.  Then I realized that people don't read carefully or with undivided attention.  It would be easy for someone to misread it to mean "time of last login".  It's the kind of thing that would be considered when you "idiot-proof" the guide.

Answer (score 1):

> **Duration** *noun*
>   The time during which something continues.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/duration)

*Duration* measures the length of time of an *event*, the 'something' that 'continues'. In context, your sentence #1 doesn't point to any relevant event, and to call *everything that happened since the last login* an 'event' seems to overreach. Between the two options, #2 sounds better.

If you are looking for something more concise than *length of time*, consider "*Time elapsed* since the last login".

> **Elapse** *verb*
>   (of time) pass or go by.
>   ‘Various factors, including the time elapsing between any remarks and the trial, can affect this.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elapse)